# How can I get python3.4 to find the PySDL2 module I downloaded on win7?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pysdl2

I downloaded pySDL2 (from https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2/downloads) and unzipped the SDL2 package to my folder C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PySDL2-0.9.3, which has a subfolder sdl2 which has a subfolder ext.

I also copied a 'hello world' program to the same folder, using the header:

```
import os
os.environ["PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"] = "/Python34/Lib/site-packages/PySDL2-0.9.3"
import sys
import sdl2.ext
```

I ran it from the same folder, and It said it couldn't find sdl2.
(I used the os.environ line, since I had already 'set' the environment variable, but it didn't help)

ImportError: could not find any library for SDL2 (PYSDL2_DLL_PATH: /Python34/Lib
/site-packages/PySDL2-0.9.3/sdl2)

So I ran pip install PySDL2, and that said:
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PySDL2-0.9.3>pip install pysdl2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pysdl2 in c:\python34\
lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...

So, I have the package in the python library, I have it pointed to in the environment, and pip says its already there, but somehow python can't find it to import.

What should I be doing?

Comment: I had to download the DLL and point to it with os.environ["PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"] after installing with PIP. Don't think is expected behavior but at least it works.

Answer (score 2):

PySDL2 doesn't come with the SDL2 libraries.

You need the SDL2 libraries for PySDL2 to work. SDL2 is the library that does all the hard work. PySDL2 is just the interface to allow you to access it from Python.

Have a look at http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html for details about how to install it. And then look at http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html for information about how to use PYSDL2_DLL_PATH

For my projects I chose not to install PySDL2 in Python at all. I put all the PySDL2 stuff in a project subdirectory called "sdl2", and all the Windows SDL2 DLLs in a separate subdirectory called "sdl2_dll". Then in the root directory of the project I have the following file called sdlimport.py

```
"""Imports PySDL2 

This module imports PySDL2 and the SDL2 libraries held within the project
structure (i.e. not installed in Python or in the system).

Setup:

    [myproject]
     |-sdlimport.py
     |-main.py
     |-[sdl2]
     |  |-The PySDL2 files
     |-[sdl2_dll]
        |-SDL2.dll
        |-SDL2_image.dll
        |-SDL2_mixer.dll
        |-SDL2_ttf.dll
        |-and all the other dlls needed

    Edit sdlimport.py to include which bits of sdl2 you need.

Example:

    from sdlimport import *
    sdl2.dostuff()

"""

import os

# app_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "..")
app_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
"""str:  the path to your project, detected at import time
"""
sdl2_dll_path = os.path.join(app_dir, "sdl2_dll")
os.environ["PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"] = sdl2_dll_path

#--- Comment these out as needed ---
import sdl2
import sdl2.sdlimage
import sdl2.sdlttf
#import sdl2.sdlgfx 
#import sdl2.sdlmixer 
import sdl2.ext
```

Then, in each file that needs pysdl2, use `from sdlimport import *`

Answer (score 0):

On mine I had to do this in order for it to realize where sdl2 was (after i downloaded sdl2,pysdl2 already installed).

import os

os.environ["PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"] = r"c:\yourdirectory"

import sdl2.ext

It would not work any other way i tried. just change to your directory where the sdl2.dll is.